# ios NSDateFormatter transform date result error

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

my code is as fllow:

```
    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    fmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone;
    NSString *selfStr = [fmt stringFromDate:self];
    NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:selfStr];
```

if i set self = @"2022-04-13",the date will be "2022-04-13 10:00:00 +0000"
then i transform date to timestamp will be not "2022-04-13 00:00:00"

i can't know why?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to drop the time portion of the current date is

```
NSCalendar *cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
NSDate *date = [cal startOfDayForDate:NSDate.date];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Consider that the date string `2022-04-13 10:00:00 +0000` shows the UTC time zone. It's the same point in time as `2022-04-13 00:00:00 -1000`